# Not resize the game image on Samsung tablet 10.1(1280x800) using andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I developing the game using andengine. Its working fine(Automatically resize the images) for all screen resolution except in Tablet screen size (1280x800). I used this code

```
displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);   
    //Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    CAMERA_WIDTH=displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    CAMERA_HEIGHT=displayMetrics.heightPixels;       

    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    final Engine engine = new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new  FillResolutionPolicy(), this.mCamera).setNeedsSound(true));      
    return engine;
```

For game logo and menu screen i used
    private static int CAMERA_WIDTH =720;
    private static  int CAMERA_HEIGHT =480;
Its working fine (Automatically Resize the images)in  tablet after i changing in manifest file

```
   <supports-screens  android:largeScreens="true"/>
```

But inside in the game play its not resizing. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this is the `supports-screens` tag:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

By the way, changing the camera size depending on screen isn't a good idea. Remember, the camera size is the rectangle size of your scene that is actually shown on the device screen. If there are different camera sizes for different devices, and means that each device will see the game differently, and that should not be done (It would be weird, maybe unfair... and more)

You can set the camera width & height to constans, and then use `RatioResolutionPolicy` to use as much of the screen as possible.

Comment: Set the camera sizes to constants, and use `RatioResolutionPolicy`

Comment: thanks. i set contants camera size, now its working fine. I used FillResolutionPolicy()

Comment: I used Accelerometer in my game.  In tablet its working as opposite direction. Any solution ?

Comment: Well, what does it mean 'opposite direction'? does it give you negative values in the AccelerometerData when they should be positive, for example?

Comment: public void onAccelerometerChanged(final AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData) {

  if(pAccelerometerData.getX()<-2)
     {
//moving a ball up direction
      }
     else if (pAccelerometerData.getX()>2)
 {
//moving a ball down direction
 }


Its working fine in other android devices, But in tablet

it moves

 if(pAccelerometerData.getX()<-2)
     {
//moving a ball up direction --->moving left
      }
     else if (pAccelerometerData.getX()>2)
 {
//moving a ball down direction--->moving right
 }


}

Comment: `AccelerometerData.getX()` should be used for right-left movements, not up-down. When you hold a device horizontally and tilt it right-left, the X values are changing. Tilt it forward-backward and Y values are changing.

Comment: if I choose constant sizes like 800x480 then I need to make the graphics file in photoshop with size of 800x480 and design the sprites on it? Your help!